# How to get the remaining in java

Tags: java

I have a java program that will run every 15th and last day of the month, i have sample that has 2 different type of amount.

this type of amount is come from the query and its already sort by sysdate, this is the result of the query:

130
500

while running the program it will automatically deduct from the first amount  and the remaining will go to the second amount.

this is first amount 125.

and this is the second amount 100.

how do i do that? it really appreciated your help.

//this is the query to get the 130,500.

```
String getAdvanceEmployee = "SELECT AMOUNT FROM CFV_CHARGES WHERE EMP_NO = '40000124' AND TO_DATE(DUE_DATE) = '30-JUN-19' AND IS_ADVANCE = '1'";
ResultSet result1 = stmt.executeQuery(getAdvanceEmployee);


while(result1.next()){

String amount = result1.getString("AMOUNT");
//the output 130,150


//this is the query to get the 125. 

String getAdvancePayment = "SELECT AMOUNT FROM CFV_CHARGES WHERE EMP_NO = '40000124' AND TO_DATE(DUE_DATE) = '30-JUN-19' AND ENTRY_TYPE = '1'";
    ResultSet result2 = stmt1.executeQuery(getAdvancePayment);


while(result1.next()){

String amount = result1.getString("AMOUNT");
//the output will 125


    //im confused the logic itself


 }
}
```

amount from the query:
130
500

the first amount 125
the second amount 100

actual result is:

125
-125 // this negative comes from the amount of 130 the remaining -5 will go to the next amount which is this

100
-5
-95

//and the remaining last was -405.

Comment: What have you tried? What isn't working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can calculate it this way :

```
public int calculatAmountOne(int firstAmount , int secondAmount){
//in your case firstAmount = 125 , secondeAmount = 130 
int rest = firstAmount - secondeAmount ;
return rest 
}

public int calculatAmountTwo(int firstAmount , int secondAmount){
//in your case firstAmount = 100, secondeAmount = -5
int rest = firstAmount + secondeAmount ;
return rest 
}
```

so now that you create the two method to calculate the two different amount you can use them

```
int restOne = calculatAmountOne(125,130) // restOne = -5 ;
int restTwo = calculatAmountTwo(100,restOne) // restTwo = 95 ;
int lastRemaining = restTwo + 500 // lastRemaining = 595
```

you should later use number that you get instead of the number i put as example based on your question !